# Upload file from memory to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have downloaded a csv file from S3 into memory and edited the file using Boto3 and Python. How can I can reupload this file to S3 without ever storing it locally?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any functions in the Boto3 docs that looked promising but did not fit your use case for some reason?

Comment: But why just edit the file inside of S3?

Comment: I don't know how Boto3 sends files but Python has `io.StringIO` and `io.BytesIO` to create file-like object in memory so it can be used as opened file - it has functions like `read()`, `seek()`, `write()`, `flush()` etc.

Comment: From a quick look, I can see the [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) method from the `Client` class which should do exactly as you asked.

Comment: The `put_object` method worked, thank you James. Sorry for the terrible question

Comment: @Ciaran No problem. I know that searching through docs when learning a new technology, API, etc. can be daunting. However, it is quite rewarding to get familiar with those docs ASAP. In the future, if you have other questions like this, I would strongly recommend searching through the docs a bit first. If you still have the question afterwards, feel free to ask the SO community, just make sure you mentioned what you have looked into and why what you found hasn't worked for you.

Answer (score 11):

As per @JamesMchugh, from [`put_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object):

```py
response = client.put_object(
    Body=b'bytes'|file,
    Bucket='string',
    Key='string',
)
```

Comment: Is there a faster way than this? I am trying to upload a file of size approx 2GB. Other functions such as upload_file needs to store the file locally first.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I have a list of dictionaries and I have to create in memory file and save that on S3. Following Code works for me!

```
import csv
import boto3
from io import StringIO
# input list
list_of_dicts = [{'name': 'name 1', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'name 2', 'age': 26}, {'name': 'name 3', 'age': 27}]

# convert list of dicts to list of lists
file_data = []
header = list(list_of_dicts[0].keys())
file_data = [[d[key] for key in header] for d in list_of_dicts]
file_data = [header] + file_data

# create in memory file and write data to it.
file_to_save = StringIO()
csv.writer(file_to_save).writerows(file_data)
file_to_save = bytes(file_to_save.getvalue(), encoding='utf-8')
file_name_on_s3 = 'my_data.csv'

# save in memory file to S3
client = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id='your access key',
                      aws_secret_access_key='your secret key')
response = client.put_object(
    Body=file_to_save,
    Bucket='your bucket name',
    Key=file_name_on_s3,
)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to encode the file before saving? Can it not be saved as it's written by csv.writer?

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use the `boto3.resource`'s `Object.put()` method.

For example:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
  's3',
  endpoint_url=endpoint,
  aws_access_key_id=access_key,
  aws_secret_access_key=secret
  )

s3_resource.Object(bucket, str(prefix + remote_file)).put(Body=os.urandom(1000000))
```